# regex to select text before term

Tags: ruby

I have some strings that have the same pattern:

"abc 1x de"
"abc 2x rf"
"abc 3x gh"

I need to select "x" and the number before "x".
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: I assume `x` as well as the preceding number, are unknown, only that there are one or more digits followed by letter in the string. In that case, you can use the regular expression,`/(\d+)([a-z])\b/i`. If there is a match, capture group 1 will hold the digit(s) and capture group 2 will hold the letter. [Demo](https://rubular.com/r/Jf7CMwKOF1Ygn2).

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the `\b` word boundary using [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-scan). Using Ruby 3.0.2:

```rb
["abc 1x de", "abc 2x rf", "abc 3x gh", "4x ABC", "ABC 5x"].
 flat_map { _1.scan /\b(?:\d+x)\b/ }
#=> ["1x", "2x", "3x", "4x", "5x"]
```

As long as `x` doesn't appear in your other strings, this will work regardless of how many digits you have, or where the substring appears in your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
["abc 1x de","abc 2x rf","abc 3x gh","4x ABC" "ABC 5x"].map { |s| s[/(?>\dx)/] }
=> ["1x", "2x", "3x", "4x"]
```